# Reading from file into a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm using C++ and I'm reading from a file lines like this:

```
D x1 x2 x3 y1
```

My code has:

```
struct gate {
    char name;
    vector <string> inputs;
    string output;
};
```

In the `main` function:

```
vector <gate> eco;

int c=0;
int n=0;
int x = line.length();
while(netlist[c][0])
{
    eco.push_back(gate());
    eco[n].name = netlist[c][0];
    eco[n].output[0] = netlist[c][x-2];
    eco[n].output[1] = netlist[c][x-1];
}
```

where `netlist` is a 2D array I have copied the file into.

I need help to loop over the inputs and save them in the vector `eco`.

Comment: Why don't you read directly into the vector instead?

Comment: This is very confusing and the code is incomplete. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish or why.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t fully understand the sense of the 2D array but I suspect it’s redundant. You should use this code:

```
ifstream somefile(path);
vector<gate> eco;
gate g;

while (somefile >> g)
    eco.push_back(g);

// or, simpler, requiring #include <iterator>
vector<gate> eco(std::istream_iterator<gate>(somefile),
                 std::istream_iterator<gate>());
```

And overload `operator >>` appropriately for your type `gate`:

```
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& in, gate& value) {
    // Error checking … return as soon as a failure is encountered.
    if (not (in >> gate.name))
        return in;

    gate.inputs.resize(3);
    return in >> gate.inputs[0] >>
                 gate.inputs[1] >>
                 gate.inputs[2] >>
                 gate.output;
}
```

Comment: @Jerry It was ironic. I’m more appalled that two people dispensed upvotes without realising that I’d posted utter bullsh*t.